# result type and redefinition in c++

Tags: java, c++

I'm wondering how does c++ accept redefining methods with changed result types ?
This is not acceptable in java and I want to understand the mechanism , here is an example of a code , it makes perfectly no sense but it is just a simple example :

```
#ifndef __revision__Ex1b__
#define __revision__Ex1b__

#include <iostream>

class Ex1b {
public:
Ex1b f() {
    return *(new Ex1b()) ;
}

};

#endif /* defined(__revision__Ex1b__) */

#ifndef __revision__Ex1b2__
#define __revision__Ex1b2__

#include <iostream>
#include "Ex1b.h"

class Ex1b2 : public Ex1b  {

public:
std::string f() { std::string ch = "dhfkjn" ;
    return ch ;
}
};

#endif /* defined(__revision__Ex1b2__) */
```

in Java this is not acceptable , the method f must have the same result type in both Ex1b and Ex1b2.
Thanks for help

Comment: Note that name using double underscores anywhere are reserved for the implementation (the C++ compiler and its standard library) and you are not allowed to even utter them except where explicitly granted permission (e.g. permission is granted for `__cplusplus` and `__FILE__`).

Comment: Also note that `Ex1b::f()` causes a memory leak on every invocation! If you want to create a temporary in C++ you just use `Ex1b()`. In C++ you rarely use `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, this is not *overriding* the function (like it would be in Java), but instead it's *hiding* the base member function. [It's document here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html), and other places on the web. In order to *override* a function in C++, you need to make it *virtual* (and if you were overriding it, you'd get an error like you would in Java, but you're not overriding it here).

`Ex1b2` now has *two* different methods, each named `f()`. To call the base class's version, you would call `Ex1b::f()`.

Comment: And interestingly, doing `using Ex1b::f;` in the derived class doesn't cause a conflict due to §7.3.3/15. The base function will still be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the method is not redefined in the subclass, Instead, it is *hiding* the method in the superclass. One is not a redefinition of the other, so they are not incompatible. This is because you haven't declared the function f() in the superclass as *virtual*.

In Java, methods are virtual by default, so you see the  error. If on the other hand you declare the method in the superclass as "final" (making it non-virtual) then you will just get a different error, because you can not override a final method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the responses given by others, it is worth pointing out that the return type can even change when overriding a `virtual` function, although only within some constraints. In C++ pointer and reference return types can be *covariant*. That is a derived class can return a pointer or reference to a further derived type. For example:

```
struct B {
    virtual B* clone() const { return new B (*this);
};
struct D: B {
    D* clone() const override { return new D(*this); }
};
```